# JS array formatting pulling from js object

Tags: javascript, metadata

A bit of a new hobbyist and I'm working with some pre-existing code and trying to find a way to slice the array.map pull in the code instead of having it just have it write as a flat object.

Original code:

```js
  const restructuredAttributes = {};
  jsonData.attributes.map((attr) => {
    restructuredAttributes[attr.trait_type] = attr.value;
  }, []);
```

The result it output into the new file is as follows:

```js
"attributes":[
  "Attribute One":"trait one",
  "Another attribute":"Another trait",
  "And another":"And another trait"
```

but this is my desired result:

```js
"attributes": [
  {
    "Attribute": "trait",
  },
  {
    "Another attribute": "Another trait",
  },
  {
    "And another": "And another trait"
  }
```

I have attempted to modify a bit (working on beginner knowledge, tbh) and tried to insert the {} manually as seen below:

```js
const restructuredAttributes = {};
jsonData.attributes.map((attr) => {
  restructuredAttributes["{" + attr.trait_type] = attr.value + "}";
}, []);
```

but they end up inside of the "" pulled from the js object

```js
"attributes": [
  "{Attribute One": "trait one}",
  "{Another attribute": "Another trait}",
  "{And another": "And another trait}"
```

Any input or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're confusing JSON with real objects. JSON is a text format. Just as you wouldn't expect `"[" + { prop: "value" } + "]"` to give you an array, you shouldn't expect tacking on `"{"` ... `"}"` to give you an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an object with a single property based on your `attr` value.
The `map` method of the array returns a new array based on the result of the loop.

```js
const restructuredAttributes = jsonData.attributes.map((attr) => ({
  [attr.trait_type]: attr.value;
}));
```

Comment: This is fantastic and oh so close!  Thank you!  Follow up, is there a way to get rid of the numbered iterations that show up?

        "attributes": [
          {
            "0": {
              "Background": "Uncommon"
            },
            "1": {
              "Skeleton": "White"
            },
            "2": {
              "Clothing": "Green Tank"
            },
            "3": {
              "Eyes": "Green Crossed"
            },
            "4": {
              "Accessory": "Grey Beard"
            },
            "5": {
              "He

Comment: Well, no. Those are the indexes of the array. That's just part of how JS works. The indexes are only shown in the console. But the example you're showing is different from the result what my answer produces. Please share what `jsonData.attributes` looks like (in your question) to be sure.

Comment: No worries at all, I was able to hobby fiddle with it and got the exact results I needed :)  Thank you so much, Emiel!